# Facing Issue when the NEST DLL upgraded for elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a .csproj(.NET 4.6.1 version) which consumes ElasticSearch.net and Nest nuget packages, today these dll's are upgraded to new version 7.1.0.

Since ElasticSearch.net has a dependency on System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource (>= 4.5.1) the dll is upgraded to the dependent version.

when the code is run the below error shows up.

[image: Error Message]

To overcome the above issue a dependent assembly is included in the app.config as below but there is no luck with the changes done, any help highly appreciated.

```
 <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.1" newVersion="4.0.3.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: what version did you upgrade from?

Comment: it is upgraded from 6.0.0

Comment: I can't replicate the issue you're seeing in this example: https://github.com/russcam/NestFullFrameworkExample. Miught be worth comparing what you have in csproj and config with that example?

Comment: @Russ Cam Thanks for the suggestion, consumer of our class library had a version mismatch with the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource dll once consumer project was modified to utilize specific version privately, the issue got resolved. Example Reproduced :https://github.com/mahanteshk/ElasticSearch-DependencyCheck